# Change v-model value without changin the actual data

Tags: vue.js

So i've this data

```
data: () => ({
    products: [
        { id: 1, name: "Prod 1", price: 2, stock: 5 },
        { id: 2, name: "Prod 2", price: 3, stock: 6 }
    ]
})
```

Template

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr v-for="product in products" :key="product.id">
            <td>{{ product.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
            <td>
                <input
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                v-model="product.price"
                @paste.prevent
              />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                maxlength="999"
                v-model="product.stock"
                @paste.prevent
                @keypress="onlyNumber($event)"
                @input="handleInputStock($event.target.value)"
                @blur="updateStock($event.target.value, product.id)"
              />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So what I want is that when the user hit delete/backspace from the `stock input field` the value cannot be empty (blank) or it must be greater than or equal to zero. but without changing the `products.stock` value. this is because I need the `product.stock` value to compare with the changed value `(stock input field)` before sending to the server. So if stock value is equal to `product.stock` don't send to server otherwise send and update stock value.

so here's what i've done so far.

prevent the stock value empty but not working

```
handleInputStock(value) {
  return +value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
},
```

update stock

```
updateStock(stock, productId) {
  const productStock = this.products.find(product => product.id == productId).stock;

  if (!(stock == productStock)) {
    // do ajax
  }
},
```

onlyNumber

```
onlyNumber(e) {
  const charCode = e.which ? e.which : event.keyCode;
  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Can we have two versions of `products`? One for the server, one for v-models.

```
var server_products = [
    { id: 1, name: "Prod 1", stock: 5 },
    { id: 2, name: "Prod 2", stock: 6 }
]

//...

data: () => ({
    products = server_products
})
updateStock(stock, productId) {
  server_products.forEach((product) => {
      if(product.id === productId && stock !== product.stock){
        product.stock = stock
        // do ajax
      }
  })
},
//...
```

If not than you can use vue's [`watch`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-vs-Watched-Property) property so vue finds changes to the array for you.

```js
//...
data: () => ({
    products: [
        { id: 1, name: "Prod 1", stock: 5 },
        { id: 2, name: "Prod 2", stock: 6 }
    ]
}),
watch: {
    'products': {
        handler: function(newValue) {
            // do ajax
        },
        deep: true
    }
}
//...
```

Comment: hmm i was thinking the same thing but the reason why i'm asking this question. maybe i can have a better solution rather than have two version of products.

Comment: You can use [`watch`](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-vs-Watched-Property)  to execute commands on changes in data in vue

Comment: using watch it gives the whole object so if there are two inputs and one of these input values changes you don't know which object key is changed.

Answer (score 1):

Personally this feels like a higher level question to which your flow of product editing needs tweaking. Here is what I can think of:

1. User enters all the information.
2. User hits submit button.
3. Check whether of not the stock count is empty or 0.
4. Return an error message if it is.
5. Submit and update otherwise.

It might be worth looking into [vuelidate](https://vuelidate.js.org/) that handles such validation in JavaScript. Meanwhile, we are also coming up with a tool called [CRUDS DS](https://crudds.com/) (a WIP) that handles such situation with ease.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to create a `ProductComponent` and watch every product separately inside its own component, as shown below:

**Product.vue**

```
<ProductComponent 
   v-for="product in products" 
   :product="product" 
   :key="product.id" />
```

**ProductComponent.vue**

```
<template>
   <tr>
      <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
      <td>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            v-model="product.price"
            @paste.prevent
          />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            maxlength="999"
            v-model="product.stock"
            @paste.prevent
            @keypress="onlyNumber($event)"
            @blur="updateStock($event.target.value, product.id)"
          />
       </td>
   </tr>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    product: {
      type: Object,
      default: {},
    },
  },

  data: () => ({ actual_stock: "" })
  
  // this is for handle stock cannot be empty or GTE:0
  // also you dont need handleInputStock anymore
  watch: {
     product: {
        handler(val) {
           this.actual_stock = val.stock;
        },
        immediate: true,
     },
     "product.stock": function (newVal, oldVal) {
        this.product.stock = +newVal;
     },
  },

  methods: {
     updateStock(stock, productId) {
        if (!(stock == this.actual_stock)) {
           // do ajax
        }
     }
  }
}
</script>
```

If you want to handle it on parent side, you may use `$emit` to send an event upwards.